# Show custom field based on variation dropdown selection

Tags: jquery, wordpress, variables, conditional-statements, dropdown

EDIT: Solution was to place the jQuery code in the header.php

I have a dropdown with number of guests. Below that is a custom field I added that customer needs to fill. Problem I have is I want the field to be hidden until customer selects 4+ value in dropdown.

This is what I have for now, but it's not working:

Dropdown with values:

```
<select id="no-of-guests" class="" name="attribute_no-of-guests" data-attribute_name="attribute_no-of-guests" "="" data-show_option_none="yes">

  <option value="">Choose No. of Guests</option>

  <option value="2" class="attached enabled">2</option>

  <option value="3" class="attached enabled">3</option>

  <option value="4+" class="attached enabled">4+</option>

</select>
```

DIV to display when option value 4+ is selected

```
<div class="wccpf-fields-group-1">  

    <table class="wccpf_fields_table  no-of-guests-wrapper" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="wccpf_label"><label class=" no-of-guests-label" for="no_of_guests">No. of Guests</label></td>
                <td class="wccpf_value">
                                        <input type="number" class="wccpf-field no-of-guests" name="no_of_guests" value="" placeholder="Please enter the number of guests arriving" min="6" max="" step="1" wccpf-type="number" wccpf-pattern="number" wccpf-mandatory="no">
                    <span class="wccpf-validation-message wccpf-is-valid-1">This field can't be Empty</span>
                                    </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

And finally the jQuery:

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery(document).on('change', '#no-of-guests',  function () {
            if(jQuery("#no-of-guests").val() == "4+"){
                jQuery(".wccpf-fields-group-1").show();
            } else {
                jQuery(".wccpf-fields-group-1").hide();
            }
        });     
    });
```

... and CSS:

```
.wccpf-fields-group-1{display:none;}
```

Comment: When you choose "4+", the script execute the show() ? add some "console.log("test");"  to see the path your code take.

An alternate way is to use the jQuery css method: 

$(".wccpf-fields-group-1").css("display", "none");

$(".wccpf-fields-group-1").css("display", "block");

instead of show()/hide().